# Conditional Regular Expression in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am parsing multiple HTML files using RegEx in Excel VBA (i know not the best thing to do) but I have this case which can either be - Scenario 1:

```
<span class="big vc vc_2 "><strong><i class="icon icon-angle-circled-down text-danger"></i>&pound;51,038</strong> <span class="small">(-2.12%)</span></span>
```

or could be - Scenario 2:

```
<span class="big vc vc_2 "><strong><i class="icon icon-angle-circled-up text-success"></i>&pound;292,539</strong> <span class="small">(14.13%)</span></span>
```

If the class ends in `danger`, I want to return `-51038` and `-2.12%`
If the class ends in `success`, I want to return `+292539` and `14.13%`

The code I have been using for the second scenario and works fine is:

```
Sub Test()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<i class=""icon icon-angle-circled-up text-success""></i>([\s\S]*?)<"
        sValue = HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(.Execute(sContent).Item(0).SubMatches(0))
    End With

sValue = CleanString(sValue)
End sub

Function HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(sText)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Open
        With .createElement("textarea")
            .innerHTML = sText
            HtmlSpecialCharsDecode = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Function

Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
     .Global = True
     .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
    CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the question is how can I use a conditional way to pick up "danger" and "success" classes and return the numbers with the correct signs + -

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add some more capturing groups with "or" conditions in them.  In your case, you want the group `(success|danger)` (also `(up|down)` based on the examples).  Then, instead of just checking the ***only*** submatch, check for the conditions that you put in your pattern:

```
Dim regex As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim expr As String

expr = "<i class=""icon icon-angle-circled-(up|down) text-(success|danger)""></i>(.*?)</.*\((.*)%\)<.*"

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = expr
    Set matches = .Execute(sContent)
End With

Dim isDanger As Boolean

If matches.Count > 0 Then
    isDanger = (HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(matches.item(0).SubMatches(1)) = "danger")
    sValue1 = HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(matches.item(0).SubMatches(2))
    sValue2 = HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(matches.item(0).SubMatches(3))
End If

If isDanger Then
    'Was "danger"
    Debug.Print -CLng(CleanString(sValue1))
    Debug.Print -CDbl(sValue2)
Else
    'Was "success"
    Debug.Print CLng(CleanString(sValue1))
    Debug.Print CDbl(sValue2)
End If
```

Comment: i have tried modifying your code but it doesn't work as expected.. Here is exactly how the pattern looks like, on the page I am trying to work with: http://bit.ly/1GIFQws

Comment: <span class="big vc vc_2 "><strong><i class="icon icon-angle-circled-up text-success"></i>&pound;9,899</strong> <span class="small">(2.86%)</span></span>

Comment: so I need to return 2 matches in the above example: 9,899 and 2.86%

Comment: @JoannaMikalai - You just need to add another matching group and continue the regex further into the string.  See edit, note that you'll have to declare `sValue1` and `sValue2` instead of just `sValue`. After looking at the source, you can probably also simplify the expression above to `"<i class="".*text-(success|danger)""></i>(.*?)</.*\((.*)%\)<.*"` and subtract 1 from each of the `.SubMatches(#)` indexes.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai - BTW, I missed it before, but the `[\s\S]*?` in your original regex can be simplified to `.*`. The `\s` is any whitespace, the `\S` is any *non*-whitespace, the `*` is zero or more times, and `?` is zero or one time. Makes more sense to just take any character (`.`) zero or more times:  `.*`.